# Scala wants from me apply method

Tags: scala, syntax

```
import java.util.Random
class Kostka {
    val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val value: List[Int] = List(rand.nextInt(6+1))
}
object MyRandom {
    def Fill[A](n: Int): List[A] = {
        if (n<=0) Nil
        else {
            var lst = List[A]
            for (i <- 1 to n){
                lst ++= (new Kostka).value
        }   
            return lst
        }
    }   
}
object Gra {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("Podaj liczbe kosci\n")
        val kosci: List[Kostka] = MyRandom.Fill[Kostka](10)
        // Policzenie wyniku
        println("Strzelaj ile razem wypadło\n")
        // przyjecie wyniku
        // dopisac ile wypadlo czyli wynik
        println("Wypadlo: ")
        println(kosci.toString)
    }
}
```

And error:

```
a.scala:10: error: missing arguments for method apply in object     List;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially   applied function
            var lst = List[A]
                      ^
one error found
```

When I have:

```
var lst = List[A]()
```

i got that error:

```
a.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Any]
 required: List[A]
                lst ++= (new Kostka).value
                ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your declaration of lst you forgot the parens : `lst = List[A]()`
In fact, `List[A](a,b,c)` is a synthatic sugar for `List[A].apply(a,b,c)`, that's why the compiler complained about `apply`'s arguments.

Edit: you can use a `ListBuffer` instead of your List (in the `Fill` method, and by the way, the name should be fill(cf http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/)) . When you finish the work to do on the buffer, you can call toList, which computes on constant time ;) .

Comment: @matiit: `List` is immutable. `ListBuffer` is mutable. Choose the one that best serves your needs.

Comment: In particular, adding an element to the end of a `List`, like you do with `lst ++= (new Kostka).value`, is expensive, as `lst` needs to be copied. Adding an element to the end of a `List` takes constant time.

Answer (score 1):

See [Aymen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126917/scala-wants-from-me-apply-method/3126958#3126958) for general guidelines. After your update you have the following effect.

`Kostka.value` has type `List[Int]`. `lst` has type `List[A]`. The result of the append (`++`) is the least common supertype of `List[Int]` and `List[A]` which is `List[Any]`. But `List[Any]` is not a subtype of `List[A]`. That's why you get the type mismatch.

Your `Fill` method should not be generic in the first place, unless you make `Kostka` generic, too.

Furthermore, the use of `new Kostka` combined with the PRNG initialization looks strange as well.

Finally, in Scala 2.8 there is a `fill` method on the collection companions:

```
scala> val r = new java.util.Random
r: java.util.Random = java.util.Random@14a616

scala> List.fill(10) {r.nextInt(6+1)}
res4: List[Int] = List(3, 6, 4, 1, 2, 4, 0, 4, 6, 4)
```

and, unless your dice are 7-sided, you might go for

```
scala> List.fill(10) {r.nextInt(6) + 1}
res5: List[Int] = List(2, 5, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 6, 3)
```

instead.